# webpage works well on all browsers except Android Browser, which shows fonts with increased size

Tags: android, html, css, fonts

I created a webpage, that works well with all major browsers. I tested and adopted the website also to mobile browsers. Unfortunately, I didn't test the page when developing on Android browser and didn't know about the problems (Android 4.2).

the following viewport works well with iPhone 5 and mobile browsers like mobile chrome.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
```

..and I would rather not change that.

I also did some media queries which work well on mobile devices.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 420px)
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 980px)
```

The webpage is wrapped in a container of 977px and I use fonts of 24px and 16px, which both show up much bigger on Android browser (Android 4.2).
Anybody with suggestions how to solve that font problem?

I tried CSS font-size-adjust and text-size-adjust but I am not able to solve hat problem, in contrary I get different output in various browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a sleepless night I found myself a solution that works.

I put Javascript/JQuery script before the end of the "body" section to  reduce the font-size in the android browser to fit in the main navigation bar.

With the first if statement I avoid that the pixel-changes also appear in chrome android browser, the nested if statement targets the android browser.

```
 <script>

    if(!(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1)) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('android') > -1)  {
               $('#mainnav nav ul li a').css('font-size','18px'); 
         }

    }

 </script>
```

This script could probably be optimized also for other android browser, since I did not test all.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a density issue. Add the `target-densitydpi` to the viewport tag. Remember this will be used on GB but not greater devices. Check this out http://www.petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/ for more detail.

Comment: Unfortunately the Android browser (Android 4.2) does not respond to target-densitydpi. As you already mentioned --> deprecated.